# Make AVD work faster

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am using AVD on my laptop and it's very very slow.

My laptop configuration is:

Intel i5 2.6ghz
16GB 1600Mhz RAM
512GB SSD

What can I do to make emulator work very very fast?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: Short question: why? :) This is very annoying...

Comment: what is the ram size of your emulator?

Comment: Have you tried editing the AVD and enabling `Use Host GPU`? Might help a little.

Comment: Why? Because emulation depends heavily on your CPU and RAM (and less on GPU). So the only way to make it work faster is getting a better CPU and more RAM (and a better GPU), but since you have a laptop, these are really not choices (except maybe the RAM part).

Comment: I5 is not good enough? 16GB is not good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download and use HAXM (Hardware Acceleration Execution Manager ) from [Intel's android site](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android)

See this site for [installation](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-atom-x86-image-for-android-ice-cream-sandwich-installation-instructions-recommended) and optimization